# Can terraforms null_resource use timeouts blocks?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform `null_resource` that looks like the following

```
resource "null_resource" "foo" {

 provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "foo.sh"
 }
}
```

So what I would like to know is I can use timeouts with the resource as in the following

```
resource "null_resource" "foo" {

 provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "foo.sh"
 }

 timeouts {
  create = "60m"
  delete = "2h"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the `null` provider doesn't support timeout operations for it's resources.

However, there should be a way to model this using [destroy-time provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#destroy-time-provisioners).

```
resource "null_resource" "foo" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "timeout 60m foo.sh"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "timeout 2h foo.sh"
    when    = "destroy"
  }
}
```